# why select box move in react material UI?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

I have a select box and text input why select box move up ?? why it is not in same level of input field ?

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/r7lq1jnjl4

document
https://material-ui.com/demos/selects/
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because in your code, you have added `margin="normal"` on  component which sets an extra margin on it.

You should be able to solve it easily by

a. adding `alignItems='center'` to the `<Grid container spacing={8} alignItems='center'>`

or

b. remove that margin config from the text input component and add the margin manually from your css.

Comment: after that it come just few margin below toinput?

Comment: will I add class into it  and add margin

Comment: You can add class and update the margin in your css.